# How to hash the return string from WCF service to client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

I have a service that gets a card account number (16 digits). A website (MVC) will call that service then will return a card including the account number.

Since account number is a confidential information, I must only return the last four digits of card account number to the website but inside the service, the full account number must retain.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where your service gets card number from?

Comment: Does the MVC application ever need to call the service with the full account number?  Or is it simply requesting information regarding the card based on other, non sensitive information?

Comment: It don't need the full account number but the last four only. The full account number must stay within the service only because i need it for other methods in the service such as validations. The last four is only needed in the MVC application for displaying purposes.

Comment: Are these other methods called from the MVC application?  If so, is there other identifying information that the MVC application would have that could be used by the service to get the full account number?  Marco's solution below is one approach, but there's a possibility of hash code collisions, so I'm asking to see if there's another piece of information that is guaranteed to be unique (like customer number or something).

Comment: Yes, those methods are called from the MVC application. There is, the card id.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this in your service:

Have a Dictionary to store the hash of the card and the card number:

```
var cards = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var cardNumber = "1234123412341234" 

cards.Add(cardNumber.GetHashCode(), cardNumber);
```

This is a simple solution, but there are so many unknowns: is your service stateless as it should, if so you need to persist the dictionary, but maybe because the right solution to this problem, would be to use some kind of caching systems, such as memcache.

Comment: Yes , my service is stateless .. I will try this solution .. Thanks !

Comment: It is possible for the hashcode for two different values to be the same - this would result in a duplicate key exception if OP is storing a large number of cards in the dictionary.

Comment: But very unlikely if using  a better hash algorithm. This was just a simple idea, so that the op as something where to start from.